# searchbox in angular 2 doesn't return the whole object

Tags: html, angular, search-box

I'm very new to Angular2 and 4.
I have a list of items of type class (Item).
Items fields are name, price and description.
I want to make a searchbox when the user types the name of the item, it displays the correct item object.

I followed this example: http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/03/simple-search-using-pipe-in-angular-2.html
but It didnt work, I think because if was searching between strings not objects of type item.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the code in the tutorial, with an array of objects you just need to update the return statement of the transform method in your Angular2 Pipe like this:

```
return value.filter(function (el: any) {
                return el.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
            })
```

PS: I added el.name but you can search through the description or whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom pipe and pass search parameters to that pipe, something like below example

```
<li *ngFor="let n of list | FilterPipe: queryString : searchableList ">
      {{n.name}} ({{n.age}})
</li>

 this.searchableList = ['name','age']
```

And your custom pipe

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'FilterPipe',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, input: string,searchableList : any) {
        if (input) {
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            return value.filter(function (el: any) {
                var isTrue = false;
                for(var k in searchableList ){
                  if(el[searchableList[k]].toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1){
                    isTrue = true;
                  }
                  if(isTrue){
                    return el
                  }
                }
                
            })
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```